# calling grep from a bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I'm new to bash scripts (and the *nix shell altogether) but I'm trying to write this script to make grepping a codebase easier.

I have written this

```
#!/bin/bash
args=("$@");
for arg in args
 grep arg * */* */*/* */*/*/* */*/*/*/*;
done
```

when I try to run it, this is what happens:

```
~/Work/richmond $ ./f.sh "\$_REQUEST\['a'\]"
./f.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `grep'
./f.sh: line 4: `       grep arg * */* */*/* */*/*/* */*/*/*/*;'
~/Work/richmond $
```

How do I do this properly?

And, I think a more important question is, how can I make grep recurse through subdirectories properly like this?

Any other tips and/or pitfalls with shell scripting and using bash in general would also be appreciated.

Comment: PS: You can get rid of one line by using `for arg`: It's a shortcut for `for arg in "$@"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax error is because you're missing `do`. As for searching recursively if your `grep` has the `-R` option you would do:

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg in "$@"; do
   grep -R "$arg" *
done
```

Otherwise you could use `find`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg in "$@"; do
   find . -exec grep "$arg" {} +
done
```

In the latter example, `find` will execute `grep` and replace the `{}` braces with the file names it finds, starting in the current directory `.`.

(Notice that I also changed `arg` to `"$arg"`. You need the dollar sign to get the variable's value, and the quotes tell the shell to treat its value as one big word, even if `$arg` contains spaces or newlines.)

Comment: When iterating over command line arguments, you can also omit the "$@" and write it as just "for arg; do ..."

Answer (score 3):

On recusive grepping:

Depending on your grep version, you can pass -R to your grep command to have it search Recursively (in subdirectories).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is stated above, but try putting your statement in back ticks:

```
`grep ...`
```

Comment: There is no reason to use backticks (or the preferred `$()`) in the OP's script or in any version posted in answers so far. If he was assigning the result to a variable or using it in-line as an argument to another command, that would be different.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'find' plus 'xargs' to do the file searching.

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "$arg" /dev/null
done
```

The '`-print0`' and '`-0`' options assume you're using GNU `grep` and ensure that the script works even if there are spaces or other unexpected characters in your path names.  Using `xargs` like this is more efficient than having `find` execute it for each file; the `/dev/null` appears in the argument list so `grep` always reports the name of the file containing the match.

You might decide to simplify life - perhaps - by combining all the searches into one using either `egrep` or `grep -E`.  An optimization would be to capture the output from `find` once and then feed that to `xargs` on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [findrepo](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/findrepo) script which may give you some pointers

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a better grep and don't want to do anything yourself, use ack, which you can get at http://betterthangrep.com/.